# IE 8 rendering quirks mode

Tags: html, internet-explorer, quirks-mode

I know this is a old problem, and there are alot of fixes for this. I have applied the following, but still some of my users get the quirks mode. And its only users that run IE 8.

```
<!doctype html>
```

and

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

It seems like this is not enough, the page is still rendering in quirksmode in IE 8.

Since this is an umbraco/c# site, the first row in the source is empty. This is because of the Master directive in the top. You cannot move  above it. See picture.

[image]

This is some code from the site.

```
<!doctype html>

<!-- paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ -->
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!-- Consider adding an manifest.appcache: h5bp.com/d/Offline -->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js" lang="sv">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Use the .htaccess and remove these lines to avoid edge case issues.
       More info: h5bp.com/b/378 -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

The source is like this.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
<!doctype html>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Configuration" %>
<!-- paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ -->
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!-- Consider adding an manifest.appcache: h5bp.com/d/Offline -->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js" lang="sv">
```

The "Master" creates the empty line in the top.

Installing Google Chrome Frame fixes the problem, but due to citrix environments some of our users don't have the full control to install plugins.

Comment: please post the URL if you can

Comment: Don't forget, the DOCTYPE has to be the first none-whitespace in the HTML sent down.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Henri Sivonen’s page [Activating Browser Modes with Doctype](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/), which discusses the IE 8/9 specialties as well and (despite the page name) also factors other than doctype declaration that may affect browser mode.

Answer (score 0):

Is the page on an intranet? I believe IE8 defaults to quirks mode in that case. You could set a group policy to get around this though.